# Moving to root view controller without showing child views

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, childviewcontroller, rootviewcontroller

I want to dismiss all child views and finally move to root view controller. I used the following code

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion:nil)
}
```

But issue is that while moving to root view , it showing child view first  then root view .

How can i solve the issue? any idea?

Comment: try this `var vc: UIViewController? = presentingViewController
        while ((vc?.presentingViewController) != nil) {
            vc = vc?.presentingViewController
        }
        vc?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { _ in })`

Comment: Have you tried (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)

Comment: Issue still exist.

Comment: Which method you using to show new `ViewController` ... PUSH or PRESENT?

Comment: As you jumping to first viewController (In appdelegate etc) use that same code.

Comment: PRESENT to show  new view controller

Answer (score 0):

Use `popToRootViewController` method of navigation controller object.

ex: `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

This method will pop to the root view controller by popping all the view controller in between the current view controller to root view controller.

Comment: Moving to root view is working perfect , but don't know why it showing child view first then root view.

Answer (score 0):

Use this it will dismiss all presented `UIViewController`'s and go to rootViewcontroller

```
self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

And if you call it from somewhere else, you would need to pass the controller and replace self with the controller

Comment: Actually i have 2 child views and one root view. i called the dismiss from top of second child. So it shows first child then after it shows root view. Don't know why it shows this intermediate child window instead of direct root window

Comment: View or ViewController?

Comment: I mean viewcontroller

Comment: Okay ... Try this ... `self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`